# Java 8 Lambda Map<Integer,List<Object> for each create a new object and add this new objet in a list

Tags: java, lambda

Java 8 Lambda Map  for each create a new object and add this new objet in a list

This is my firts step

```
Map<Integer, List<Obj>> objGroupBy = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getSomething)); 


List<Obj2> lst2= new ArrayList<Obj2>();

for (Entry<Integer, List<Obj>> entry : objGroupBy .entrySet())
{
    lst2.add(new Obj2(entry.getKey().intValue(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

I want to know if it possible to do it in lambda
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: You really think I don't try lol!

Comment: What other explanation is there to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent to your code:

```
List<Obj2> lst2 = list.stream()
                      .map(o -> new Obj2(o.getSomething(), o))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now if you really want to start the same way:

```
List<Obj2> lst2 = list.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getSomething))
                      .entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .map(e -> new Obj2(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```